# Django PasswordResetView not working properly with app_name causing DisallowedRedirect

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm encountering an issue with Django's built-in password reset functionality within my project. Specifically, I have an app named 'user' and I've defined the app_name variable in my urls.py as app_name = 'user'. However, this seems to be causing problems with Django's password reset views.

Initially, I encountered the "Reverse for 'url name' not found" error when using auth_views.PasswordResetView. To address this, I tried setting the success_url parameter to 'user:password_reset_done' and providing a custom email_template_name.

However, now I'm facing a new issue where the debugger is raising a DisallowedRedirect exception with the message "Unsafe redirect to URL with protocol 'user'" when attempting to access the password reset functionality. This occurs during the execution of django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView.
the error is:

```
Unsafe redirect to URL with protocol 'user'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/reset_password/
Django Version: 5.0.2
Exception Type: DisallowedRedirect
Exception Value:    
Unsafe redirect to URL with protocol 'user'
Raised during:  django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView
```

Here's a summary of my setup:

urls.py (within the 'user' app):

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'user'
urlpatterns = [
        path('reset_password/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='registration/reset_password.html',
                                                              success_url='user:password_reset_done', 
                                                                email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html'),
                name="reset_password"),
        path('reset_password_sent/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_done.html'),
                name='password_reset_done'),
        path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
                name='password_reset_confirm'),
        path('reset_password_complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),
                name='password_reset_complete')
]
```

registration/reset_password.html:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Password reset</h1>
<p>Forgotten your password? Enter your email address below, and we’ll email instructions for setting a new one.</p>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_div }}
    <input type="submit" id="reset_password" value="Reset my password">
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

registration/password_reset_done.html:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Password reset sent</h1>
<p>We've emailed you instructions for setting your password.</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

registration/password_reset_email.html:

```
Someone asked for a password reset for email {{ email }}. Follow the link below:
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'user:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

I've tried various approaches but haven't been able to resolve this issue, I scoured Stack Overflow for potential solutions, yet unfortunately, none of them yielded the desired outcome.. Any insights or suggestions on how to address this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!